# How to add a custom command macro in Windows 8 speech recognition

Tags: windows-8, macros, speech-recognition

I have tried a few options but its not working for me. I am using Windows 8 Pro.
Can anyone show me how I can write my own custom command macros for speech recognition in Windows 8?

I have tried [Windows Speech Recognition Macros](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13045) from Microsoft. But it seems to support Windows Vista and Windows 7 only.

Answer (score 1):

[Dragonfly](https://github.com/t4ngo/dragonfly) allows you to write custom voice commands in Python for Dragon Naturally Speaking as well as Windows Speech Recognition.  It's quite powerful and allows complex speech grammars and can run arbitrary Python code in response to different voice commands.

Answer (score 0):

The WSR Toolkit Version 3 will do that for you. http://www.mymsspeech.com/

You can create custom Windows Speech Recognition macros with it. It's payware and costs $29.99 (retrieved on July 19, 2013). It's compatible with Windows 8, 7 and Vista.

> It is certified Windows 8 Compatible and previously Vista and Windows 7 Compatible.
>   (http://www.mymsspeech.com/p/3/wsrtoolkit)